# Range от min до max

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно реализовать подобный range `без jquery` и `др. библиотек`, на `нативном JS`?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать через HTML5:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/godKwW

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="line" 
    oninput="testMy()" value="0">
<div id="my">0 %</div>

function testMy() {
line = document.getElementById("line").value;
my = document.getElementById("my");
my.innerHTML =line+ "%";
}

body {
    padding: 30px;
}
input[type=range] {
    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */


    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 300px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}

/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1px;

    /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
    background: transparent;

    /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 6px 0;

    /*remove default tick marks*/
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ccc;
}
```